# How to rerender output panel on change apex selectList

Tags: apex, visualforce, actionfunction

I want to display different picklist values on selecting another picklist value. So i have put one on change event in the first selectlist and using action function i'm passing the selected attribute value to the controller. But my controller method which is referred in action function is not getting called atleast. Here is my code

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountRecTypeChange_CLS">
 <apex:form >
<apex:actionFunction name="changeTier" action="{!mymet}" reRender="tierId"/>
<apex:outputPanel id="recTypeId">
  <apex:selectList value="{!strRecTypeName}" size="1" multiselect="false">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!recTypeList}"/>
  </apex:selectList>
  </apex:outputPanel>
  <apex:outputPanel id="tierId">
  <apex:selectList value="{!strTier1}" size="1" multiselect="false" onchange="changeTier();">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Tier1_ClassificationList}"/>
  </apex:selectList>
  <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!CustomSave}"/>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller :

```
public PageReference mymet() {

return null;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ActionSupport` tag to `rerender` the section. You do't need actionfunction and controller method.

```
<apex:selectList value="{!strTier1}" size="1" multiselect="false" onchange="changeTier();">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Tier1_ClassificationList}"/>
      <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="tierId"/> //onselect
  </apex:selectList>
```

Comment: But i need to display the results retrieved from the controller method

Comment: @ram135868 in case you can call controller method from `actionsupport`

Comment: thanks tushar. Please help me in this thing alone. I am getting the selected recordtype name from the selectlist. But by updating the record's recordtype using recordtypename , it is not getting updated. Can u pls tell me how to get recordtypeid and update the record

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add an  around the section, e.g.

```
    <apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountRecTypeChange_CLS">
 <apex:form >
<apex:actionFunction name="changeTier" action="{!mymet}" reRender="tierId"/>
<apex:actionRegion>
<apex:outputPanel id="recTypeId">
  <apex:selectList value="{!strRecTypeName}" size="1" multiselect="false">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!recTypeList}"/>
  </apex:selectList>
  </apex:outputPanel>
  <apex:outputPanel id="tierId">
  <apex:selectList value="{!strTier1}" size="1" multiselect="false" onchange="changeTier();">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Tier1_ClassificationList}"/>
  </apex:selectList>
  <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!CustomSave}"/>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:actionRegion>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Nope that didnt work